# Gravity inside the earth with non-uniform density

Tags: physics

I want to compute gravity inside the earth in different layers I have their thickness and density, can you please help me which formula I can use for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to have anything to do with how to use the software Wolfram *Mathematica*.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to *Mathematica* at all. If you edit your question to explain how you want to use *Mathematica* for your problem, we can release the hold.

Answer (score 2):

The only physically reasonable model is spherical shells of different density.

As Isaac Newton showed, you can model the gravitational attraction of a spherically density-symmetric sphere as a point mass at the center.  Thus all you need do is calculate the total mass between $r=0$ and $r = r_0$ (your test point), and then the force is:

$$ F = {G\ M(r_0)\ m \over r_0^2} $$

where $ M(r) $ is the total mass $ 0 \leq r \leq r_0 $.

$$ M(r_0) = \int\limits_{r = 0}^{r_0} 4 \pi r^2 \rho(r)\ \mathrm dr $$

where $ \rho(r) $ is the density at radius $ r $.